# Agent traning Failed

Tags: dialogflow-es

Every time while saving training phrases for intent get following message.

> Agent training failed
>   Internal error occured: 3643ac92-3137-44a0-bb39-ab85ce4c9af0
>
> Agent traning Failed 
>   Internal error occured :1013c13d-625b-4e84-811c-4ec57fd1854b

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue following the below approach:

1. Go to Google developer console(https://console.cloud.google.com)
2. Delete the maps project linked to our agent.

I am still curious about how this worked. Tried different things, but could not come to any conclusion. I guess that's the price I have to pay for using third party NLP service. I integrated maps prebuilt agent, and since then this behavior started appearing. Later removed the map project from the console, and it started working again.

I am curious to know if you have succeeded in resolving yours.